# fgets() Not Ignoring New Line

Tags: c, newline, fgets

For my practice assignment I have to use either gets() or fgets(). 
I chose fgets() as its more secure.

The first input is meant to be able to hold a maximum of 5 characters. 
So i gave the char array a size of 6 to accommodate the trailing '\0'.

I found the fgets() issue of it adding a trailing '\n' when you press Enter (using stdin with fgets())

I done a bit of research and found a for loop to try and get rid of it. However, it doesnt seem to be working and i cant for the life of me figure out why.

Its still skipping the next input when i type in 5 characters.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Declare char arrays
    char    arcInputString5[6];
    char    arcInputString10[11];
    char    arcInputString15[16];
    char    arcInputString20[21];
    int     clean1, clean2, clean3, clean4;
//  int     nStrLen1, nStrLen2, nStrLen3, nStrLen4;
//  nStrLen1 = nStrLen2 = nStrLen3 = nStrLen4 = 0;

printf("\nPlease Input String 1 - Max Length 5: ");
//gets(arcInputString5);
fgets(arcInputString5, 6, stdin);

for(clean1 = 0; clean1 < strlen(arcInputString5); clean1++)
{
    if(arcInputString5[clean1] == '\n' || arcInputString5[clean1] == '\r')
    {
        arcInputString5[clean1] = '\0';
        break;
    }
}

printf("\nPlease Input String 2 - Max Length 10: ");
//gets(arcInputString10);
fgets(arcInputString10, 10, stdin);

printf("\nPlease Input String 3 - Max Length 15: ");
//gets(arcInputString15);
fgets(arcInputString15, 15, stdin);

printf("\nPlease Input String 4 - Max Length 20: ");
//gets(arcInputString20);
fgets(arcInputString20, 20, stdin);

printf("\nThankyou For Your Inputs - They Are Shown Back To You Below\n");

puts(arcInputString5);
puts(arcInputString10);
puts(arcInputString15);
puts(arcInputString20);

printf("\nThe String Lengths For Each Input Are Listed Below");

printf("\n%d", strlen(arcInputString5));
printf("\n%d", strlen(arcInputString10));
printf("\n%d", strlen(arcInputString15));
printf("\n%d", strlen(arcInputString20));
```

}

Ive tried multiple ways of doing the for loop such as using the number 6 instead of "strlen(arcInputString5)"

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

EXAMPLE INPUT:

```
asd d
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
Please Input String 2 - Max Length 10: //skips this
Please Input String 3 - Max Length 15: //this is the next line for input
```

Comment: please show exact sample input and output of the program.

Comment: Not so much 'adding newline' as 'not removing newline'.  The Enter key provides a newline; the `gets()` function removes that from the returned string, but `fgets()` does not -- which at least gives you a chance to detect whether you got a complete line or whether the input line was truncated for lack of space.

Comment: As a general rule, don't restrict the input to just 5 characters; allow (for sake of argument) 256 characters of input, and then check that the user didn't type more than 5 characters (apart from the newline).  This largely avoids problems of having to clean up the extra data from over-long strings.  Actually, I'd use 4096 as the default length for the input (rather than just 256), but choose any large enough value that you won't be likely to run into problems.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. During testing i did increase the size and obviously it worked ok but i was very curious why it didnt work here. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Dr.Pepper For fun: "[Dr Pepper](http://www.drpeppermuseum.com/About-Us/History-Of-Dr--Pepper.aspx)" dropped the '.' in the 1950s.

Comment: About 40 years before my time then! Probably why i didnt know :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets()` reads *one character less* than the given buffer size from stdin and then
appends a NUL-character. So in your case, with an input buffer of 6 characters,
it reads "asd d" into `arcInputString5`, and the newline character that terminates the line input is still unread.

The next `fgets()` then reads (only) this newline character into `arcInputString10`.

You need a buffer size of (at least) 7 to read the five characters "asd d" including the
newline character from stdin.

The same applies to your other buffers used for `fgets()`.

*Added:* As  Jonathan Leffler correctly commented, a better method is to supply
a "large" input buffer to `fgets()` and check the actual length of the user input after
reading one line.

You should also note that `fgets()` returns NULL if no character could be read at all
(end-of-file), so you should check the return value.

Comment: Agreed, but note that if the users gets it wrong ant types 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' instead of just 'super', then the code has to recover from the over-long input.  And users will make such mistakes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You are completely right, my answer explains only *why* it does not work as expected. Your comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270323/fgets-not-ignoring-new-line/21270524?noredirect=1#comment32049166_21270323 to the question describes the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Change **6** to **7**:
**`arcInputString5[7];`**
**`fgets(arcInputString5, 7, stdin);`**

You need to give space for the '**\n**' and '**\0**' characters.

valter

Answer (score 0):

Call `getchar()` to retrieve the the newline character from the input stream before asking for the next user input.

I like to use the following simple function for clearing the input stream

```
void clear() {
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```